# How to get the least busy EC2 instance from Auto Scaling Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an Auto Scaling Group (generated from ECS Cluster) with a daemon type ECS task on each instance in it (WebRTC service).

My question is: how to fetch all instances of that group sorted by their average CPU usage from last minute?

Of course I can fetch all instances and then query CloudWatch get-metric-statistics for each of them but this doesn't sounds like good.

Maybe there is a better load-balancer solution for this particular case?

Comment: Metrics are one of the nice features of CloudWatch. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I can't query CloudWatch statistics for all instances at once. I need to make separate request for each of them.